# Why did James say he didn't drink?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl, supergirl-2015

James told Lucy's father he didn't drink, yet he has had drinks with Winn and Cat Grant. He also brought a bottle with him to Karas apartment in episode 13. Did I miss something?

Comment: He's hardly the first guy to have lied to try to impress his girlfriend's father. The last thing he needed was alcohol in his system to make the night any more uncomfortable than it already was.

Answer (score 7):

James didn't say that he didn't drink, he simply ordered a non-alcoholic drink while he was meeting Lucy's father for the first time, presumably because he wants to keep his head clear. Her father then uses that as a way of (not so subtly) insulting him with a [quote about meddling do-gooders](https://www.reddit.com/r/drunk/comments/1t4i48/never_trust_a_man_who_doesnt_drink/)

> **Jimmy Olsen:** *I'll just have a club soda.*
>
> **General Lane:** *Thank you.* ***“Never trust a man who doesn't drink because he's probably a self-righteous sort, a man who thinks he knows
>   right from wrong all the time.”*** *No inference intended, Jimmy.*

Comment: Can't say I agree with General Lane there. Not a very nice or open-minded thing for him to say either. :/